# Phonegap: Change style to holo (changing in manifest leading to build errors)

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to change the Android theme style in Phonegap.
I started by trying things such as:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
</gap:config-file>
```

Which I read should work, however, that and similar attempts made no difference once I build the app from command line.

So instead I went directly to AndroidManifest.xml and changed `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoTitleBar"`

This however just leads to build errors...

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The f
ollowing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null
returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\app\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build
,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: D:\app\platforms\android\co
rdova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

What am I to do to get this Phonegap app using the holo theme not the old gingerbread one?

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml, you need to change 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`